# Simpler idea for protection against reflected XSS on client side

Tags: internet-explorer, xss

I was going through some CLIENT side defenses against reflected XSS e.g. XSS auditor(chrome), IE8 XSS Filters, NoScript. They use regular expression and other sophisticated techniques. Why didn't they use any simpler idea?

My question is- why don't we store what ever is going to server as parameters and if these parameters are reflected in HTML response then discard it or encoded it. Simple idea. I feel there may be false positives but not very convincing ones. Any input?

Comment: Okay. I will not do that from now.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is- why don't we store what ever is going to server as parameters and if these parameters are reflected in HTML response then discard it or encoded it

*Any* parameters? So if I search for “Hello” and the response page contains the text “Here are your results for Hello”, it gets mangled?

There has to be some criterion for what counts as potentially dangerous, otherwise every form on the web is going to break like this. You could start out with “any parameter with a `<` in”, but then what about attribute injection attacks like `onmouseover=`, or JavaScript injection like `'; alert(document.cookie)`? And how do you stop a parameter of just `<` from breaking every tag on the page? There isn't an obvious watertight answer, which is why detection ends up being a complex mess of heuristic rules and not a clean, watertight pattern.

Personally I think client-side reflected-XSS detection is deeply misguided: in principle doomed to failure and [in practice worse than useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051632/ie8-xss-filter-what-does-it-really-do), but if you're going to do it you'll need to limit its scope because content reflection is a common property the web needs to work properly, not always an attack.

Comment: We can specify that store only when some special characters in input(with certain length) are present then check for reflection.

Comment: @Naman: which special characters? `<`? `&`? `"`? `'`? Backslash? Space? (To deal with unquoted attribute value injections.) There are many characters which could potentially cause reflected XSS issues if incorrectly handled, and if you're counting reflection of any of them as an attack you are going to get loads of false positives, more than with the complex rules currently used by IE.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a good false positive where it is bad idea? What if I HTML encode it? there will be no problem I guess.

Comment: @Naman How about on Stack Overflow - how would it then be possible to enter code examples to post to other users if you're preventing `<script>` tags and the like (see what I did there)?

Comment: The encoding will not happen in serverside. If I encode it on my browsers, other user will see it just fine.

Comment: @Naman I think I understand now. As bobince says there are too many places where this won't quite work and will break things, or other attacks will be missed.